# Reading the Realtime database directly VS using Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been reading this article about reading the realtime database directly vs calling cloud functions that returns database data.

If I am returning a fairly large chunk of data e.g. a json object that holds data representing 50 user comments from a cloud function does this count
As Outbound Data (Egress) data? If so does this cost $0.12 per gb per month?

The comments are stored like so with an incremental key.

```
comments: [0 -> {text: “Adsadsads”},
1 -> {text: “dadsacxdg”},
etc.]
```

Furthermore, I have read you can call goOffline() and goOnline() using the client sdks to stop concurrent connections. Are there any costs associated with closing and
Opening database connections or is it just the speed aspect of opening a connection every time you read?

Would it be more cost effective to call a cloud function that returns the set of 50 comments or allow the devices to read the comments directly from the database
But open/close before/after each read to the database, using orderByKey(), once(), startAt() and limitToFirst()?

e.g something like this

```
ref(‘comments’).once().orderByKey().startAt(0).limitToFirst(50).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Cloud Function reads data from Realtime Database and returns (part of) that data to the caller, you pay for the data that is read from the database (at $1/GB) and then also for the data that your Cloud Function returns to the user (at $0.12/GB).

Opening a connection to the database means data is sent from the database to the client, and you are charged for this data (typically a few KB).

Which one is more cost effective is something you can calculate once you have all parameters. I'd recommend against premature cost optimization though: Firebase has a pretty generous free tier on its Realtime Database, so I'd start reading directly from the database and seeing how much traffic that generates. Also: if you are explicitly managing the connection state, and seem uninterested in the realtime nature of Firebase, there might be better/cheaper alternatives than Firebase to fill your needs.

Comment: Hi Frank Thank you for your answer. Does the cloud functions starting up and connecting to the database have the same KB usage or is this only for the client SDKs?

Comment: That'd be the same in both cases. RTDB simple measures the bandwidth that is used to send responses.

Comment: It is not really that "generous" considering they count the entire HTTP request, SSL, and everything, not just the data you send. 1 client could consume as much 10MB in a day in your app just re-establishing the connection with your Realtime Database over and over again with as little as 100 bytes or even 0 DB data sent/received. Yes, I'm speaking from experience.

Maybe using Cloud Functions could help reduce that since it uses Firebase Admin SDK which _I heard_ that it re-uses connections.